# Do directed cyclic graphs have leaves?

Tags: graph, graph-theory

Is the notion of *leaf* only restricted to trees?

Let's say I have a directed cyclic graph. Would it be a mistake to name the nodes having only outgoing edges *leaves*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In *undirected* graphs, the common terminology is *leaf* for a node that has only one incident edge.

In *directed* graphs, the common terminology is *source* for a node that has no incoming edges and *sink* for a node that has no outgoing edges. Sometimes, if the context is clear, you will hear a sink with a single incoming edge called a *leaf*, but it's not as common.

Answer (score 0):

No, it would not be a mistake if you have 1 outgoing edge. Look at the picture here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29

"far-left is a *leaf* vertex"

The definition: "A leaf vertex is a vertex with degree one" - nothing is said, that it is restricted only to trees.